# Running a python script locally works but through travis-ci it fails, what could be the reason?

Tags: python, travis-ci

I wrote the following python script:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1:8080")
conn.request("HEAD", "/")
check = conn.getresponse()
print check.status, check.reason
if check.status == 200:
            exit(0)
else:
            exit(1)
```

When running it from my machine I get the proper response:

```
# python pytest.py
200 OK
```

But when Travis-CI runs the script at build time, the following error is thrown:

```
$ python pytest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest.py", line 4, in <module>
    check = conn.getresponse()
  File "/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
The command "python pytest.py" exited with 1.
```

Edit #1:

Here's a log to the build:
https://travis-ci.org/geek-kb/tikal_assignment/builds/182633824

What could be the reason for the failure?

Comment: Is the server running on port 80? Maybe include a `sleep 3` command? And maybe `netstat -tuna` to see if the server is up. Please provide a log to a build if you can.

Comment: I've added the build log, thanks.

Comment: @joepd, Please create an answer so I'll accept, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are running the service on port 8080 inside of the docker container:

```
Step 11 : CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

And it gets exposed as such to the host:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -t camelel/django
```

Try connecting to that port from your script, for example like this:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1:8080")
```

Comment: Adding 3 secs sleep solved the issue, but thanks I'll change the code.